# Should Symfony2 ACL be used for checking ownership in SaaS?

Tags: symfony, acl, saas, multi-tenant

In a multi tenant web application should Symfony2 ACL framework be used for checking the ownership of domain objects?

I can't get the point since (assuming each table has a back reference to the `User` object) i can simply check current user `id` against the entity owner `id`, like the following:

```
/*
 * @Route("/edit/{slug}")
 * @Method("GET|POST")
 * @Secure(roles="ROLE_USER")
 * @Template
 */
public function editAction($slug);
{
    // Find the post given the slug
    $repo    = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeHelloBundle:Post');
    $entity  = $repo->findOneBySlug($slug);
    $current = $this->get('security.contex')->getToken()->getUser();

    // 404 if slug is invalid
    if(!$entity) throw new $this->createNotFoundException();

    // AccessDenied if current user is not the owner of the entity
    if($current->getId() != $entity->getUser()->getId())
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
}
```

Maybe ACL can help avoiding back referencing each entity to the user table? Any explanation or example would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: How did you go about solving this problem? I'm facing the same issue. I am currently looking at creating a CustomAclProvider by modifying the AclProvider within Symfony to add a tenant_id to all my SELECTs and INSERTs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACL is useful when you have a scenario that  multiple people have access to same domain. [The ACL documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html) has a good example for that.

For example, lets say you have SaaS providing collaborative document editing for companies. A company may want to restrict access to a document, to only allow the executives of the company to edit it and not the employees. In that scenario, you can't use the User token alone, since multiple members needs to access to the domain. This is where the usefulness of ACL comes in.